# Under sink piping question

Tags: plumbing

Is there a better way to do this piping?
Thanks[image]

Comment: If you straighten out some of those connections and pipes, you won't need the bowl under the trap.

Answer (score 0):

flexible PVC and fingers crossed that it doesn't leak now that it's hopefully done.[image]